# grep matches exact string or with wildcard

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I want to search the content of a file that could contain for example:

```
name1
name2
name3
...
...
name10
name11
...
...
```

the search should match the string if it doesn't have a wildcard (*). for example :

```
grep -w name1 filename
```

it returns exactly what I want:

```
file1   #ignores file10 & file11 as no wildcard used
```

but when I use the same command but with wildcard (*), as follows:

```
grep -w name1* filename
```

it also returns file1 only. without file10 and file11. How can I match the string exactly as the first case and when a (*) is used it should include the others?

> Note: I have seen some answers suggested using .* instead of * it
> worked but for my application the input is coming always in the form
> of * not .*

thank you in advance.

Comment: this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) .. why do you have to use `*` and not `.*`? (ie. though I wouldn't suggest it, could you just prepend `.` to `*`?) where does the input come from? do you have to use `grep`?

Comment: @ti7 I don't have to use grep, It is just the first thing that came to my mind. the input coming from an external source with * not .*

Comment: Which other characters do you need treated as non-literal? For example if the input contained `foo` and the argument given to search for was `fo.` should that match or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` uses [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) for pattern matching. `grep -w 'name1*'` would make it match zero or more `1`s, so `name1` and `name11` would match.

If it only matches `name1` for you it's because you have a file named `name1` in the directory and the unquoted `name1*` will be interpreted by the shell (globbing). Always use quotes around your arguments that contain special characters. If you use a variable, always put `"` around it.

To make it match any name starting with `name1`, make it

```
grep -w 'name1.*' filename
```

- `.` means "any character"
- `.*` means "any character, zero or more times".

If the input comes from some external source where `*` is used as a wildcard, you need to change that string before calling [grep](/questions/tagged/grep).

Example:

```sh
search_str='name1*'
new_search_str="$(sed 's/\*/.*/g' <<< "$search_str")"
grep -w "$new_search_str" filename
```

Comment: The issue is the input recieved using * instead of the .* Is there an alternative or a way to go beyond that?

Comment: @MhdGhd I just added a way to deal with that.